# find, mdfind and locate as cron jobs?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find, locate

From what I understand there is a cron job that runs on unix systems that cache the filesystem to make quicker calls (or something like that) What is that process called and where is that database stored?

Answer (score 0):

It's called `updatedb`, docs here: http://linux.die.net/man/8/updatedb

Comment: Does this apply for OS X as well?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/109590/whats-the-equivalent-of-linuxs-updatedb-command-for-the-mac

Answer (score 0):

This applies for os X 10.10

The actual database is:

/var/db/locate.database"

NAME
     locate.updatedb -- update locate database

SYNOPSIS
     /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb

DESCRIPTION
     The locate.updatedb utility updates the database used by locate(1).  It
     is typically run once a week by the
     /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist job.

```
 The contents of the newly built database can be controlled by the
 /etc/locate.rc file.
```

ENVIRONMENT
     LOCATE_CONFIG            path to the configuration file

FILES
     /var/db/locate.database  the default database
     /etc/locate.rc           the configuration file

SEE ALSO
     locate(1), launchd(8)